# Removing dependency on Terminfo package from a GHC compiled binary

Tags: haskell, terminfo

I'd like to remove `terminfo` package from the default dependencies of my GHC installation, as the generated executable does not run in a particular environment without `libtinfo`, saying:

```
./Main: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, is there any neat way to remove dependency on `terminfo` package?
The only way I found is to use `-hide-all-packages` of `ghc` and then enumerate all required default packages via `-package` option:

```bash
ghc -hide-all-packages -package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/package.db \
  -package base -package containers -package array -package template-haskell \
  -package unix -package filepath -package process -package directory \
  -package time --make Main.hs
```

Options like `-hide-package` or `-ignore-package` doesn't work.

```bash
$ ghc -ignore-package terminfo -ignore-package ghc --make Main.hs
Loaded package environment from /home/keigoi/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.10.7/environments/default
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id ghc-8.10.7:
    ghc-8.10.7 is ignored due to an -ignore-package flag
    (use -v for more information)
```

Any ideas?

Some thoughts and additional findings:

(*) I have no idea why the generated binary depends on it -- the package is required by GHC API, which is not always necessary I think and I didn't use it.

Actually, binaries generated from the fresh installation (as of GHC 8.10 or 9.2 from `ghcup`) does not depend on `libtinfo`.
Under the circumstance that `~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.10.7/environments/default` does not exist, the generated binary has no dependency to `libtinfo`. This file is generated when you initialize Cabal. After that, the compiled binary will depend on libtinfo.so.

(**) Commands like `strip` seems not to elimite that dependency.